# Sonata Admin shows only last admin item in sitebar menu but all in dashboard

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I've got a symfony application with the [SonataAdminBundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle). In version `2.3` everything worked perfectly. When updating to version `3.1` all admins where still shown in the dashboard but only the last of a group was shown in the sitebar menu. I don't know that's a bug or if there's just a new setting I missed. The documentation for the `3.1` is unfortunately not up to date yet.

I use two admin lists to split them into two columns. Here is a snippet from the admin configuration with the groups and the items:

```
dashboard:

    blocks:
        - { position: left,  type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list, settings: { groups: [product, event] } }
        - { position: right, type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list, settings: { groups: [system] } }

    groups:
        product:
            label: group.product
            label_catalogue: MyAdminBundle
            icon: '<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>'
            items:
                - my.admin.product
                - my.admin.product_group
                - my.admin.product_image
                - my.admin.product_media_file
                - my.admin.attribute
        ...
```

In the dashboard the hole group with all 5 admins is shown. In the sidebar menu only the `my.admin.attribute` admin is shown in the product group. This goes for all groups. It's always only the last element which is shown.

Does anyone know what's the reason for this?

The project currently uses `symfony/symfony: 2.8.6` and  `sonata-project/admin-bundle: 3.1.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the SonataAdminBundle uses the `label` of the admin service as the identifier. All my services had the same label called "title" as this is just translated in the translation file for the admin anyway.

```
my.admin.product:
    class: My\Bundle\AdminBundle\Admin\ProductAdmin
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: title }
    arguments:
        - ~
        - My\Bundle\AdminBundle\Entity\Product
        - ~
```

So the solution was to simply change the label to a unique one like `product_title` and all the admins are shown again in the sidebar.

You can see the discussion and finding in [this ticket](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/3915). This is also the ticket where they are going to change the identifier to something really unique.